# Copy data from csv file that has milliseconds timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I need to import data from a csv file that contains milliseconds timestamp. When i using `\COPY` command to copy from the file, i get this error:

```bash
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "1679356641166"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
CONTEXT:  COPY call_stats, line 1, column timestamp_milli: "1679356641166"
```

The corresponding column(timestamp_milli) in hypertable has type `timestamptz`, it should be able to store milliseconds. This is my datastyle:

```bash
 DateStyle
-----------
 ISO, MDY
(1 row)
```

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/250245/parse-a-unix-epoch-value-as-a-timestamp-in-postgresql) thread answers your question.

Comment: 1) Follow the link @Stefanov.sm posted. Be aware you will need to modify your epoch value. In current raw form: `select to_timestamp(1679356641166); 09/10/55186 20:52:46.000128 PDT`. What you want `select to_timestamp(1679356641166/1000); 03/20/2023 16:57:21 PDT`. 2) You cannot directly cast to a `timestamptz`: `select 1679356641166/1000::timestamptz; ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to timestamp with time zone`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone also troubled by this problem, see the [comment link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/250245/parse-a-unix-epoch-value-as-a-timestamp-in-postgresql). If you want to keep the millisecond precision, using `to_timestamp(1679356641166/1000.0)`